# Disabling manual payments for connected Stripe accounts (standard accounts)

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Standard accounts and would like to stop connected accounts for making their own manual payments due to the need for potential refunds. According to this link (stripe.com/docs/connect/platform-controls-for-standard-accounts): "Note: If you need full control over your connected accounts’ payouts and want to restrict your connected accounts from being able to make their own payouts, contact us with a detailed description of your use case." Does anyone have any experience with how Stripe actually restricts the connected standard accounts?

I know converting to express accounts is an option but I would need to create new accounts for my many onboarded accounts and it would require a lot of resources on the back end

I reached out to Stripe support but they struggle about how to deal with it/don't escalate it up

Comment: Reaching out to Stripe Support is still better than asking SO here. Generally that statement is about Payout, not Payment (they are different things). You can restrict their Payout but can't restrict they to create Payment, as Standard Account is basically a full fledged account.

Comment: @orakaro thank you, I meant to say payouts not payments*. How can I restrict their manual payouts?

Comment: Just reach out to Stripe Support